# How to update recurring profile for paypal express checkout recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

On my website I am using paypal express checkout and creating recurring profiles.

I want to update the amount for a recurring profile and is calling the updaterecurring function as:

```
if($Post['update'] == 1) 
{
  $nvpstr="&PROFILEID=".$profileID;
  $nvpstr.="&AMT=1.2";
  $nvpstr.="&PROFILESTARTDATE=".urlencode("2014-03-01T0:0:0");
  $resArray=hash_call("UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
  $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
  return $resArray;
} 
else
{
  $resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
  $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
  if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
  {
  // if SetExpressCheckout is returned with success, move to paypal site for payments.
  RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
  } 

}
```

The update recurring profile is giving me error on paypal sandbox page. Do I need to call SetExpressCheckout before the updaterecurring call?

I am using the paypal integration lib from https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example

Comment: the update call gives me this error on paypal sandbox page " This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow." Return to merchant
At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to and try another option.

Comment: Sounds like you may be trying to update the start date of a profile that has already started.  Can you post a sample of the raw API request and response you're getting?